# Unsupported docker-compose option: init

Tags: docker-compose

I'm running docker-compose 1.25.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.  My config file looks like

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  foo:
    image: some_image
    init: true
    ...
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get

```
The compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.foo: 'init'
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#init), the `init` option was added in the version 2.2 file format.  According to [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-22), that file format is supported in Compose versions 1.13.0+.

Comment: Not tested, but you specify `version: "3"`. Doc about compose file v3 states `image.init` is available for version `3.7` and higher : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#init. Therefore, you should either upgrade version to 3.7 or 3.8, or downgrade it to 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [v3 syntax, this field was added in 3.7](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#init). So you would need to specify at least that version at the top. `3` is the same as `3.0` in older versions of compose (newer releases dropped the version field entirely):

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  foo:
    image: some_image
    init: true
...
```

Note that `docker-compose` itself is deprecated and in current releases of docker, the v1 python command has been replaced by a v2 module to the docker binary, aka `docker compose` (space rather than a dash).